# Всплывающее окно при событии hover

Tags: jquery, javascript

На странице имеется ссылка при наведении на которую нужно отобразить информативный блок с данными о пользователе. В точности как на otvety.google.
Попытка использовать bootstrap popover неудачная из-за не ассинхронности вызовов события popover и самого ajax. Знаете другие варианты?

Comment: А чем вам не нравится вариант показывать поповер, вызовом функции в колбеке аякса ?

Comment: тем, что при следующем вызове ajax - предыдущий блок popover не скрывается, я пробовал многие решения - ни один корректно не работал

Comment: сможете помочь - я оплачу работу

Comment: Смогу, но я хочу чтобы вы понимали что на гугл ответах, не происходит каждый раз аякс запрос при ховере линка. Там все поповеры, по всем линкам уже загружены, и тупо показываются/скрываются.